# How to set up Selenium to work with Visual Studio .NET using C#?

Tags: selenium

I tried to google, but there are many different ways to work with Selenium. I'm using:
- Windows 2003 Server
- Visual Studio 2008
- Selenium IDE installed through Firefox
- NUnit 2.5 is copied into C:\
- Selenium RC is copied into C:\

1. First I created a Library Project using C#.
2. And this my class :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NewTest
    {
        private ISelenium selenium;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            selenium = new DefaultSelenium( "localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://localhost:4444" );
            selenium.Start();
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                selenium.Stop();
            }
            catch( Exception )
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual( "", "" );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheNewTest()
        {
            selenium.Open( "/google.com" );
        }
    }
}
```

1. Next add all references from the C:\Selenium RC\selenium-dotnet-client-driver-1.0.1
2. Compiled the Library Project, succeeded. No errors.
3. Run NUnit.exe, now errors :(

> SeleniumTest.NewTest.TheNewTest:
>   Selenium.SeleniumException : XHR
>   ERROR: URL =
>   http://localhost:4444/google.com
>   Response_Code = 403 Error_Message =
>   Forbidden+for+Proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the Forbidden error because you are setting the baseURL to that of Selenium RC. You need to set it to http://www.google.com and then in your test would look like

```
    [Test]
    public void TheNewTest()
    {
        selenium.Open( "/" );
    }
```

or you need to change your test to

```
    [Test]
    public void TheNewTest()
    {
        selenium.Open( "http://www.google.com" );
    }
```

Comment: Hi there,
I got new errors after change it to
<pre> 
[Test]
    public void TheNewTest()
    {
        selenium.Open( "http://www.google.com" );
    }

</pre>

SeleniumTest.NewTest.TheNewTest:
Selenium.SeleniumException : ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the forum at http://clearspace.openqa.org for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Access is denied.

Comment: I tried many different ways. Even I created a Console Application instead of Class Library to test it. But it seemed freezing instead of running http://google.com. The Selenium Remote Control v.2 appeared. And this is the link opened with Firefox : http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/Blank.html?start=true

Can you tell me where did I miss?

Thanks

This is the blog:

Answer (score 0):

to setup ide for selenium in conjunction with c# is to use visual studio express. And you can nUnit as the testing framework. Below links provide you more details

[How to setup C#,nUnit and selenium client drivers on VSExpress for Automated tests](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-setup-cnunit-and-selenium-client.html?utm_source=BP_recent)

[Creating Basic Selenium web driver test case using Nunit and C#](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/creating-basic-selenium-web-driver-test.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Unit testing project
2. Add library project to your solution.
3. right click on library project select NuGet package option.
4. search selenium install first two options selenium and selenium support class.
5. Also download chrome driver, IEDriver, gecko driver if you want to perform cross-browser testing.
6. create the test class and test method in the unit testing project.

   [TestClass]
       // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
       public class Test class
      {
       [TestMethod]
       public void LoginTest()
       {
       // code
         }
       }