# Error in C# code written using Selenium libraries in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

Got help from below post:-[How to set up Selenium to work with Visual Studio .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355287/how-to-set-up-selenium-to-work-with-visual-studio-net-using-c)

When I am writing above code I am getting below error:- 
1. Error in driver variable. Error message "driver is a field but used like a type. 
2. Navigate() on braces getting Invalid token. 
3. GoToUrl -> Method must have a return type.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace BMCPerceiver
{
public class Class1
{
// Step b - Initiating webdriver
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Step c : Making driver to navigate
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://docs.seleniumhq.org/");

    //Step d 
    IWebElement myLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Download"));
    myLink.Click();

    //Step e
    driver.Quit();


   }
```

}

I have added all libraried on my Project, Please help in finding out the cause of the error's

Comment: @George Bailey - Created new question and linked to the old question as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as published is not inside a method. You'll need to use code similar to the following:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace BMCPerceiver
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            // Step b - Initiating webdriver
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            //Step c : Making driver to navigate
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://docs.seleniumhq.org/");

            //Step d 
            IWebElement myLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Download"));
            myLink.Click();

            //Step e
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```